# How to nest an Airflow DAG dynamically?

Tags: airflow

I have a simple DAG of three operators. The first one is `PythonOperator` with our own functionality, the other two are standard operators from `airflow.contrib` (`FileToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` and `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator` to be precise). They work in sequence. Our custom task produces a number of files, typically between 2 and 5, depending on the parameters. All of these files have to be processed by subsequent tasks separately. That means I want several downstream branches, but it's unknowable how many exactly before the DAG is run.

How would you approach this problem?

UPDATE:

Using `BranchPythonOperator` that jhnclvr mentioned in his [another reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44636828/8184313) as a point of departure, I created an operator that would skip or continue executing a branch, depending on condition. This approach is feasible only because highest possible number of branches is known and sufficiently small.

The operator:

```
class SkipOperator(PythonOperator):
    def execute(self, context):
        boolean = super(SkipOperator, self).execute(context)
        session = settings.Session()
        for task in context['task'].downstream_list:
            if boolean is False:
                ti = TaskInstance(
                    task, execution_date=context['ti'].execution_date)
                ti.state = State.SKIPPED
                ti.start_date = datetime.now()
                ti.end_date = datetime.now()
                session.merge(ti)
        session.commit()
        session.close()
```

Usage:

```
def check(i, templates_dict=None, **kwargs):
    return len(templates_dict["data_list"].split(",")) > i

dag = DAG(
    dag_name,
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None
)

load = CustomOperator(
    task_id="load_op",
    bash_command=' '.join([
        './command.sh'
        '--data-list {{ dag_run.conf["data_list"]|join(",") }}'
    ]),
    dag=dag
)

for i in range(0, 5):
    condition = SkipOperator(
        task_id=f"{dag_name}_condition_{i}",
        python_callable=partial(check, i),
        provide_context=True,
        templates_dict={"data_list": '{{ dag_run.conf["data_list"]|join(",") }}'},
        dag=dag
    )
    gs_filename = 'prefix_{{ dag_run.conf["data_list"][%d] }}.json' % i

    load_to_gcs = CustomFileToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
        task_id=f"{dag_name}_to_gs_{i}",
        src='/tmp/{{ run_id }}_%d.{{ dag_run.conf["file_extension"] }}' % i,
        bucket=gs_bucket,
        dst=gs_filename,
        mime_type='application/json',
        google_cloud_storage_conn_id=connection_id,
        dag=dag
    )
    load_to_bq = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id=f"{dag_name}_to_bq_{i}",
        bucket=gs_bucket,
        source_objects=[gs_filename, ],
        source_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
        destination_project_dataset_table='myproject.temp_{{ dag_run.conf["data_list"][%d] }}' % i,
        bigquery_conn_id=connection_id,
        schema_fields={},
        google_cloud_storage_conn_id=connection_id,
        write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
        dag=dag
    )

    condition.set_upstream(load)
    load_to_gcs.set_upstream(condition)
    load_to_bq.set_upstream(load_to_gcs)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[See a similar (but different) question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44626883/tasks-added-to-dag-during-runtime-fail-to-be-scheduled)

Basically, you can't add tasks to a `DAG` when it's running. You would need to know ahead of time how many tasks you wanted to add.

You could process N files using a single operator.

Or, if you have another separate dag that processes a file you could trigger that `DAG` N times, passing the name of the file in the conf.

[See here for an example of the `TriggerDagRunOperator`.](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_trigger_controller_dag.py)

[See here for the `DAG` that would be triggered.](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_trigger_target_dag.py)

[And lastly see this post from which the above examples are from.](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/airflow-lesson-1-triggerdagrunoperator-siddharth-anand)